# jQuery .on delegate not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a simple code but it seems that the .on delegation does not work? Please help?

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me!" id="button0" class=".button" />
<br/><input type="button" value="Add" id="add_button" />
<script>
    var idx = 1;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document.body).on('click',".button",function(){
            alert(this.id);
        });
        $('#add_button').on('click',function(){
            $('<input type="button" value="Click Me!" class=".button" />')
                .attr('id','button' + idx++)
                .insertBefore($(this).prev());
        });
    });
</script>
```

The "Click Me!" button should alert the ID attribute of the button, while the add button should add another "Click Me!" button with a different ID attribute value. http://jsfiddle.net/SrwrK/

Please take note that I am trying to have a workaround with the .live() method of jQuery since it has been deprecated and removed from 1.9.

Comment: the "Click Me!" button doesn't have a class of `button` it has a class of `.button`, which would be represented with a selector of `'.\\.button'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me!" id="button0" class=".button" />
```

This code is incorrect - remove the "." from in front of the button class.  Classnames only get the "." in CSS selectors like in a CSS file or in a jQuery selector statement.

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me!" id="button0" class="button" />
```

This will work.  The button you generate with jQuery has the same problem, so make it look like this:

```
$('<input type="button" value="Click Me!" class="button" />')
```

You could even simplify it a bit more like this:

```
$('<input type="button" value="Click Me!" class="button" id="button' + idx++ + '" />')
```

That will let you skip the .attr() method.

Here's a working JSfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/SrwrK/1/

Comment: ok that fixed it, but the click event of the added buttons should also implement the same event right? but it doesn't

Comment: I updated my answer.  You have the same problem in the button that you're generating in jQuery.  The `.button` class is referred to as `button` in HTML, both static and generated.

Comment: I didn't see it either at first, and I was looking for it.  :)